# python application dependency fastavro

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, pip, rhel7

Trying to install pip package **fastavro==0.23.4** on linux rhel 7.8 but getting error:

```
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/fastavro
    gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.6m -c fastavro/_read.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/fastavro/_read.o
    fastavro/_read.c:4:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
     #include "Python.h"
                        ^
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-p3u2ii2c/fastavro/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-57h05ysx-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-p3u2ii2c/fastavro/
```

I already have python3 devel packages:

```
yum list installed|grep -i devel|grep -i python
python-devel.x86_64             2.7.5-88.el7       @rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms
rh-python36-python-devel.x86_64 3.6.9-2.el7        @rhui-rhel-server-rhui-rhscl-7-rpms
rh-python38-python-devel.x86_64 3.8.0-15.el7       @rhui-rhel-server-rhui-rhscl-7-rpms
```

How can I resolve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this issue by manually downloading package: "python3-devel-3.6.8-13.el7.x86_64.rpm" on my rhel machine, installing it using yum and running the pyhton3 pip install again.